# How to remove chevron in the upper-left corner of the screen (back button) of apple watch?

Tags: viewcontroller, apple-watch

I'm using a hierarchical interface for apple watch application. Once a new interface controller is push onto the screen, it will have a chevron in the upper-left corner of the screen:

[image]

However, I would like to remove this chevron/back button, and use the "green tick" button to pop to root view controller. I don't want the user to be able to go back to the previous screen. (I have a total of 4 views)

How to do it?

Comment: Hi OP, were you able to find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no API in WatchKit to control the visibility of the chevron at this time.

Comment: Not as far as I can tell, no.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround, but it might not be optimal

```
[Controller1 reloadRootControllersWithNames:@ [ @"Controller2" ] contexts:nil];
```

Instead of a nice transition to the new screen you get a loading circle and then the new view appears.

Comment: There is no function named `reloadRootControllersWithNames` ! I think you just posted one off line from your code.

Comment: It's part of WKInterfaceController - 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/WKInterfaceController/reloadRootControllersWithNames:contexts:

Comment: Ok, I was wrong - although `reloadRootControllersWithNames` is for page-based apps, while the Chevron shows up in hierarchical navigation apps... and it might not be appropriate to use this function on a Hierarchical app. (I tried using it in my app and the user flow became un-intuitive.)